# How does C# lay out data?

Tags: c#

I am a new user of C# (for work), coming from C++ development.  I'm used to knowing more or less how data is laid out, and how many levels of pointer indirection there are, as these things can be very important for performance.

I know I'm supposed to just relax and have a good time hammering out business software and not think about these details on the clock, but is there good documentation for this for C# somewhere?

I know there is compilation to IR, and then JIT to native code, so I guess I am asking about how C# source relates to the native x86-64 code.

Comment: You can start looking into this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/67ef8sbd.aspx

Comment: This is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow; but if you’re into this, you could look at the source of particular parts of the runtime, e.g. [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) (the .NET Core runtime) and [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn). The C# language specificiation is [also available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) and you can probably learn a lot about inner works by just looking at the generated IL of code you write.